Postfix install on docker desktop don't send email and I find no logs
I need to set up a postfix server to send emails. After a few searches, I stumbled upon this tutorial: https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu.
Because I remember the pain it was to install and configure postfix, I thought about automating the install procedure using Docker. The goal is to test postfix locally using a dummy domain (postfix-01.mydomain.com), and then avoid having to go through the entire procedure when going live.
Dockerfile

debconf-utils is used to provide values for the question we're asked during a classic and interactive install of Postfix.
uproute2 is for running the ss(socket stats) test after the installation is complete.
entrypoint.sh is used to run postfix as a service (/etc/init.d/postfix start)

FROM ubuntu:22.04 AS builder

# update apt
# install debconf-utils for pre-configuration (-y says yes or default to all questions during install)
# install iproute2 for running ss (socket stats)
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y debconf-utils && \
        apt-get install -y iproute2

# Pre-configure Postfix with debconf-set-selections
# see https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/e4dd448513cb425b5ec398f95cda2462
RUN echo "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type select internet_site" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "postfix postfix/mydomain string mydomain.com" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "postfix postfix/mailname  string postfix-01.mydomain.com" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "postfix postfix/root_address  string me@gmail.com" | debconf-set-selections

# Install postfix with pre-populated selections
RUN apt-get install -y postfix
EXPOSE 25 465

# COPY configuration file
COPY conf/main.cf /etc/postfix/main.cf

# Entrypoint script to start Postfix
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Start Postfix service
/etc/init.d/postfix start

# Keep the container running
tail -f /dev/null

main.cf
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = postfix-01.mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = postfix-01.mydomain.com, $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
maillog_file = /dev/stdout

Build Command
docker build -t postfix:ubuntu.22.04 --no-cache --progress=plain . 

Run Command
docker run -d --name postfix-ubuntu.22.04 --hostname postfix-01.mydomain.com -p 25:25 -p 465:465 postfix:ubuntu.22.04

Problem: sendmail doesn't work and there's no log
echo "test email" | sendmail me@gmail.com

Tests & Checks

Postfix is running

# postfix status
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is running: PID: 583


Socket Stats shows empty values in the process column

ss -lnpt
State              Recv-Q              Send-Q                           Local Address:Port                           Peer Address:Port             Process             
LISTEN             0                   100                                    0.0.0.0:25                                  0.0.0.0:*                                    
LISTEN             0                   100                                       [::]:25                                     [::]:*                                    


master.cf shows that logs should be output to stdout`

postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd

